# Surface integral of cylinder

Tags: surface-integrals

> A cylinder surface in $(x,y,z)$-space is given by the parametric form:
>
> $$ \begin{bmatrix}
>   x  \\
>   y  \\
>   z 
>  \end{bmatrix}=r(u,v)=\begin{bmatrix}
>   \exp(u)+\exp(-u)  \\
>   2u  \\
>   v(\exp(u)-\exp(-u)) 
>  \end{bmatrix}, 0 \leq u \leq 1, 0 \leq v \leq 1$$
>
> Determine its area.

---

I'm not sure how to approach this. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surface area $\iint \|dS\|$

what is $dS$?

$(\frac {\partial x}{\partial u},\frac{\partial y}{\partial u},\frac{\partial z}{\partial u})\times (\frac {\partial x}{\partial v},\frac{\partial y}{\partial v},\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}) \ du \ dv$